# SSIS fails after changing Excel connection string - DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have designed an ETL package with SSDT to import 12 Excel sheets into my destination database. The Excel sheets are reports from another system, Iteraplan in my case. Each of the Excel reports are a snapshot of the system. There are slight changes in each of these reports, but still I have defined only one connection string to the Excel reports because, in the future, there will be more reports, and I want the connection to sources to be parametric, so that after the package is deployed, users can choose the source and the package imports data independent of me.

The structure of my ETL package is one ParentPackage, which contains more than 20 **Execute Package Task**, in which another child package is called. Since I am still designing, as not all reports have exactly same schema, when I change the Excel connection string and refer to another Excel report, some of the packages in the "Execute Package Task" fail.

There is no driver issue, as I have installed ACE 32 bit, Run64BitRunTime is False (I have also tried True, but still same behavior), DelayValidation is True, and my original package, which is designed based on September reports, is working well. The only problem is, whenever I change Excel connection string, there are random failures of some of the child packages with either of the following errors:

> DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER 
>   Error: 0xC0202009 at Parent Package: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".
>   Error: 0xC00291EC at Get Report Date From Static but Parametric Connection, Execute SQL Task: Failed to acquire connection "Static Excel Connection". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

After changing the connection, and rebuilding the project, I again get the same error, but sometimes for different child packages. At the moment, in order to solve this, I have to close SSDT, copy the excel report, delete it, paste it back, open the project again, rebuild it and then execute it. I don't understand why it is behaving this way but I am sure there should be a way to make it behave properly. I  would really appreciate it if someone shares with me their thoughts.

Comment: The error message is giving you the answer here `It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.` Either Close the file or have who ever has it open close it, or you do not have permission to write the the file in its current location..

Comment: I have administration access to the system, the Excel file is also closed. It seems SSDT itself ahs kept it locked. Because this is my server and it is my development environment, no one else is using it. I am sure.

Comment: Sometimes SSDT does do that, if you failed to import it and didn't terminate the debug correctly the file lock remains. Open up Task manager and check is excel is running in the background (as SSDT will usea background Excel task in the background if it's running); if it is, end the task and try again. If not, lose SSDT (ensuring the task stpos displaying in Task Manager) to completely release the lock and then  open it back up.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Larnu, but I this is more or less what I'm doing now. I don't want to close and reopen it each time. It is time consuming. Is there any other way?

Comment: How is your ParentPackage set up to call the ~15 child packages? How are you setting the excel connection strings?

Comment: The parent package is an "execute package task" in which a child package binds to its "PackageNameFromProjectReference" property. The Excel connection is primarily dynamic. I have defined a variable of string type containing the path of the Excel file is binded to a parameter of string type which is required. I have made it this way, so that when the package is deployed, the parameter be taken by a pop up window.

Comment: I have set the ExcelFilePath property of the Excel connection (from property>Expression>ExcelFilePath) to the value of the variable. But after facing this problem just to accelerate, I have just used a static Excel connection but still when I change it to refer to another file, it fails because of being locked! and then as I said I have to close SSDT, cut the Excel file, open SSDT, paste the Excel file to its original place to have it run.